# What kind of combinations of field components are equal under $SO(9)$ symmetry?

Tags: operators, symmetry, group-theory, lie-algebra, matrix-model

My question is a bit long and chaotic since I haven't learnt group theory systematically.

I am looking at the Banks-Fischler-Shenker-Susskind (BFSS) matrix model. It consists of 9 bosonic matrices $X_I$ and 16 fermionic matrices $\phi_\alpha$,
which transform under an $SO(9)$ $R$-symmetry in the fundamental and spinor representations.

I know the definition of $SO(9)$ rotation:
$$X'_I=R_{IJ}X_J$$
where $R_{IJ}$ is the representation of $SO(9)$.

I think the rotation invariance means:
$$<\text{Tr}X'_IX'^I>=<\text{Tr}R_{IJ}X_JR^{IJ}X^J>=<\text{Tr}X_IX^I>$$

And I know we obviously have:
$$\frac{1}{9}<\text{Tr}X_IX^I>=<\text{Tr}X_1X^1>$$
because by the meaning of $SO(9)$ rotation symmetry, the index cyclicity won't change the value. The expection should be averaged in each direction.

**My first question is, how to proof this equation explicitly by the rotation invariance in math?**
I tried to answer this question:

Find a matrix $R$
$$R=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 &0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0&  0&1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

So
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 &0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0&  0&1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X^1\\ 
X^2\\ 
X^3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
X^2\\ 
X^1\\ 
X^3
\end{bmatrix}$$

But the invariance is:
$$<\text{Tr}X_IX^I>=<\text{Tr}X'_IX'^I>=<\text{Tr}X'_1X'^1+\text{Tr}X'_2X'^2+\text{Tr}X'_3X'^3>=<\text{Tr}X_2X^2+\text{Tr}X_1X^1+\text{Tr}X_3X^3>$$

Does it make sense?

The first question relates to another question. In Appedix D of [the paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/JHEP06(2023)038), it says:

> Imposing $SO(9)$ symmetry, we find that the quantities below are determined by just 3 parameters:
> $$<\text{Tr}(X^IX^J)>=A_2\delta^{IJ}$$
> $$<\text{Tr}(X^IX^JX^KX^L)>=A_4(\delta^{IJ}\delta^{KL}+\delta^{JK}\delta^{IL})+B_4\delta^{IK}{JL}$$

I don't know how to get the two equation by math. In my naive opinion, the rotation invariance means we could change the index arbitrary without change the value, i.e. $<\text{Tr}(X^1X^2)>=<\text{Tr}(X^3X^9)>$,$<\text{Tr}(X^1X^2X^2X^3)>=<\text{Tr}(X^5X^7X^7X^3)>$, because there is no difference between 1 and 3,etc. **Am I right? Do we have more mathematical description about this?**

The last question comes from fermions, which transform under spinor representation of $SO(9)$. Then the indices are no longer the directions in spacetime, but indices of a spinor.

So my idea about "$SO(9)$ is simply rotation in spacetime and could be obtained by change index to another direction" maybe invalid.

For example, I can't say $<\text{Tr}(\phi_1 \phi_2)>=<\text{Tr}(\phi_3 \phi_2)>$ because direction 1 and 3 is equal.

**Then what kind of combinations of fermonic components  are equal under $SO(9)$ symmetry?**
For example, do we have $<\text{Tr}(\phi_1 \phi_1\phi_2\phi_2)>=<\text{Tr}(\phi_3 \phi_3\phi_2\phi_2)>=<\text{Tr}(\phi_4 \phi_4\phi_6\phi_6)>$ and so on?